# Can't Export ADT project with "Generate gradle build files" option

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, adt

[image]I wanted to work on a project with Studio. The project is currently in a different laptop and Eclipse ADT IDE.

When I try to export it with "Generate gradle build options" and click on the project, I receive the following error:

> Project ..\appcompat_v7 is missing. Needed by CHCom. Make sure all
>   dependencies are opened.

I tried:

Importing v7 from properties and restarting eclipse. When that didn't help I tried
removing v7 (Since no class is dependent on it)

My Project libraries looks like the attached image

Answer (score 2):

For folks facing similar problem, the culprit was a little line in project.properties :

```
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7
```

When I removed it, all went well.